# Unable to save Ms Teams connnector

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I am unable to save a really simple connector in Ms Teams. 
The connector I made is a part of an app, which only wraps this connector. 
As Ms suggests, I use ngrok for my endpoints (config page). (I also tried it with a real URL too with the same result.)
I can successfully include the configuration page while adding the connector to my team, but when I press the save button, it almost always fails. (55 failed, once was OK. But why !!??!!)

The script I am using:

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();

microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
        entityId: "sampleConfig24",
        configName: "sampleConfig3",
        contentUrl: "https://35e61433.ngrok.io/motivosity/msteams/config.xhtml"
    });

    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function(saveEvent)  {
        console.log("saving....");


        // microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings( function(s) {
        //  console.log(s);
        // });

        console.log("saved");

        saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });
```

The browser console contains:

```
saving....
saved


{
  "seq": 1587628706303,
  "timestamp": 1587631139034,
  "flightSettings": {
    "Name": "ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
    "AriaSDKToken": "d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033",
    "SPAEnabled": true,
    "ClassificationFilterEnabled": true,
    "ClientRoutingEnabled": true,
    "EnableYammerGroupOption": true,
    "EnableFadeMessage": false,
    "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList": false,
    "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList": false,
    "DevPortalSPAEnabled": true,
    "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage": false,
    "DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage": true
  },
  "status": 500,
  "clientType": "SkypeSpaces",
  "connectorType": "b87e49ce-e49a-4b42-895d-faf86b21d74a",
  "name": "handleMessageError"
}
```

This error message has no understandable part. Anyone knows what is this?

I also noticed, that when opening the connector page, I also see this message in the console (before pressing the save button:)
"AppsService: getInstalledAppForTeam - Invalid teamId and/or appId specified"

Comment: microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings should be written under save event function to save the provided data.Could you please try this code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqNDF.png).

Comment: Thanks for tip, but nothing has changed. 
I also tried to install the app in Admin Center / Teams / Manage Apps first, but everything is the same.
I also noticed, that when opening the connector page, I also see this message in the console (before pressing the save button:)
"AppsService: getInstalledAppForTeam - Invalid teamId and/or appId specified"

Comment: Could you please check did you added URL to the valid Domains?

Comment: Yes. I tried it with real domains, and ngrok.io domains too. The same result.

Comment: Could you please go through the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating)? Also could you please go through the sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml)

Comment: @domosi did you find a solution?